# Search not behaving as expected

Tags: search

I have the following bit of text in a vim file with cursor where the asterisk is while in insert mode:

```
\begin{document}
[latex]
Some text*
[\latex]
\end{document}

\begin{document}
[latex]
[\latex]
\end{document}
```

I want to hit ctrl-A to search for the next instance of `[latex` and insert a new line after that with this:

`inoremap ^A <esc>execute "normal! /^[latex\<cr>o"`

However, what happens instead is the first instance of `[\latex]` gets changed to `[latex]` with the cursor over the x. What has me baffled is that this works fine when I type in the keystrokes manually.

How do I get vim to do it what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Solved with this:

`inoremap <silent> <C-A> <esc>/[latex<cr>o`

I guess `execute` doesn't work when mapping keys.

Comment: `execute` didn't work as expected in your original mapping because after pressing `Esc`, you are in normal mode. But for `:execute` to work properly you need to be in command-line mode, i.e. press a colon `:`. This would have worked too: `inoremap <c-a> <esc>:execute "normal! /^[latex\<lt>cr>o"<cr>`, but your new mapping is much simpler.